# forEach for a list<Integer> takes a consumer of type list<String>, however forEach must only take super of Integer as a consumer?

Tags: java, generics

I have a program about generics and the ? super wildcard. So forEach as per oracle has the definition as

> default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)

Now in the code below, why would the forEach for ints take String list as String is not super of Integer.

```
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> nonNullStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
        
        ints.forEach(x -> {
            if (x != null) nonNullStrings.add(x.toString());
        }); 
        strings.forEach(x -> {
            if(x != null) nonNullStrings.add(x);
        });

        System.out.println(nonNullStrings);
    }
}
```

My question is about the definition of forEach as it can only take `Consumer<? super Integer>` for `ints.forEach` however, in my code, `ints.forEach` takes a `Consumer<String>` which is not super of `Integer`.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking, but I don't think `forEach` is relevant here. You could re-write this and have the exact same behavior with `for( x : myList )`.

Comment: I have question about the definition of forEach as it can only take Consumer <? super Integer> however, in my code, it take a Consumer<String> which is not super of Integer.

Comment: That `Consumer` is actually a `Consumer<Integer>`. It just converts `Integer x` to a `String` via `x.toString()` when adding each one to a `List<String>`.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing `x` is not `Integer` at `ints.forEach(x ->`?

Comment: `x` in `ints.forEach` is an `Integer`, whereas `x` in the other is `String`.

Comment: @Zircon so `x -> {if(x != null) ... }` is the accept method for Consumer interface <Integer> taking `x` as int into `accept` method ? It is clear now, thank you.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I had confusion as if forEach is taking String conumer in a list of Integer. It is clear now.

Comment: You can replace the lambda to `new Consumer<Integer> void accept(Integer x)` to make it more clear

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, or just use `ints.forEach((Integer x) -> `...